# Kusto - Print records from Table 1 that don't appear in Table 2

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to write a query inside MS Sentinel to print a full record from the SecurityAlert table that does not appear in the Security Incident table. This is done in KQL, or Kusto.

The SecurityAlert table contains a field called 'SystemAlertID' with a string value and the SecurityIncident table contains an field called 'AlertIDs' with an array of all values that could be identical to SystemAlertID from the first table.

I think the code should look something like this, but my understanding is not strong enough to make it work.

```
let Alerts = toscalar(SecurityAlert | project SystemAlertId); //I would think this pulls all alert IDs in my query time range but only selects one
let AlertsInIncidents = toscalar(SecurityIncident | where AlertIDs contains Alerts); //should create a new variable AlertInIncidents that contains all Incidents info with matching AlertIDs
let UnassociatedAlerts = toscalar(SecurityAlerts | where Alerts not in AlertsInIncidents); //this step is missing information because I am comparing fields that don't match at all. 
SecurityAlerts | where SytemAlertID in UnassociatedAlerts
```

I understand the final step is to the query SecurityAlerts table for all records that haven an SystemAlertID that does not show up in that SecurityIncident.AlertIDs array, but the logic and especially the syntax on getting there is proving very challenging.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [toscalar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction#returns)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for [!in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/not-in-cs-operator) states:

> Nested arrays are flattened into a single list of values.
> For example,
> x in (dynamic([1,[2,3]])) becomes x in (1,2,3).

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let SecurityAlert = datatable(SystemAlertId:string)
[
    "AID1", "AID2", "AID3", "AID4", "AID5"
];
let SecurityIncident = datatable(AlertIDs:dynamic)
[
    dynamic(["AID1", "AID5"]), dynamic(["AID2"]), dynamic(["AID1", "AID2"])
];
// Solution starts here.
SecurityAlert
| where SystemAlertId !in (SecurityIncident)
```

| SystemAlertId |
| --- |
| AID3 |
| AID4 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WQMWvDMBCFd4H%20w4snG0JM0mZJyBDw4qWLx%20BBta%20JQJaDdCEY%20uOjOoJUrZYH7x367l5ZolKs4NVwNYQzWXKK9WhX%20BgZV%20UY4xf4QvCjuc2JFIYYDXU3p3k6GgozB/ThG1afhvJm8kzD7Nf9zrPT9lxIcZIC4WXHulpny1k3Ud%20ivkfdZlK0%205RT2073ZFPUE1L5XT9ZNejuhYlGfvrN22ZtsUyjzX/rtV1bPPcoSzTxengOnXhcyFFoImlBim/cfwIkFWChLfK/dxQPt67JcXsBAAA=)